# Cant access Javascript multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, multidimensional-array

I have seen many of these questions on here but none seem to solve my problem. I have a multidimensional (nested) array which I am populating through query. I wish to send the final array over AJAX jQuery:

```
(function() {
    var orderDetails = [];
    orderDetails['retailer'] = [];
    orderDetails['order'] = [];

    db.transaction(function(qry){
        qry.executeSql("SELECT * FROM retailers WHERE pending = '1' ", [], function(tx, results){
            len = results.rows.length; //if rows.length, means retailer is pending so add details to array. If no length, means retailer exists
            for (var i=0; i<len; i++){ 
                console.log('start '+i+' loop in retailers qry');
                orderDetails['retailer'][i] = [];
                orderDetails['retailer'][i]['localID'] = results.rows.item(i).ID;
                orderDetails['retailer'][i]['retailerName'] = results.rows.item(i).retailerName;
                orderDetails['retailer'][i]['address'] = results.rows.item(i).address;
                orderDetails['retailer'][i]['postcode'] = results.rows.item(i).postcode;
                console.log('finish '+i+' loop in retailers qry');
            }               
        }, function(err){console.log(err)})     
    }
```

This is how I am populating the array, and here is the AJAX request:

```
        function(){
            console.log('start orders qry success callback');
            //alert(orderDetails['retailer'][0]['localID']);
            var st = JSON.stringify(orderDetails['retailer']);
            console.log(st);


            $.ajax({//send retailer to server, bring back the ID of the retailer as it is on the server so we can insert it into the order
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                //async: false,
                url: "https://www.......processOrder.php",
                data: { orderType: 'saved', orderDetails: st},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(result){

                } 
            })
        });
```

When I log the above just before the ajax request, it returns `[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]` so I know something is working, I just thought the whole contents of the object would be visible on the server side.

Also I have wrapped the whole thing in an anonymous function because I think this helps the array variable scope.

Comment: You are using the PHP associative array syntax with JavaScript arrays. They are different. A PHP associative array is roughly equal to the JavaScript object. You need to change a few `[` and `]` to `{` and `}`.

Comment: Your data will be sent to the server as POST data (i.e. in the `&param=value` format). Use `console.log($.param(st))` to see how your server will be receiving the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this
 `orderDetails['retailer'][i] = [];`
 to this
 `orderDetails['retailer'][i] = {};`

And if your `item` is not a function you want to call with parameter `i`, access it like this: `results.rows.item[i].ID`